# Replacement rule evaluates before substitution

Tags: replacement, hold

I have found similar issues in other questions, but none of the answers I found quite do what I want.

I have a list of the form

```
list={{x, a}, {y, b}, {z,c}}
```

and an expression containing functions that take `a,b,c` as arguments. `a,b,c` are symbolic. I want to use a replacement rule on my expression in which the important thing is the index of the argument, e.g. `a` in the list. To explain this better, here is a function I am using:

```
Index[list_][symbol_]:= Cases[list, {x_, symbol} -> Position[list, {x, symbol}]].
```

For example,`Index[list][a]` returns `1`, or `Index[list][c]` returns `3`.

My expression is of the form

```
... + f[a, b]g[c, a, b] + h[a] +h[b]g[a, c, c]g[b, c, b] + ...
```

i.e. there are a number of terms which contain some functions `f, g, h, ...` of a number of the symbols `a, b, c`.

I want my replacement rule to look something like

```
replace[expr] := ReplaceAll[expr, 
  {f[i_, j_]-> F[Index[list][i], Index[list][j]],
   g[i_, j_, k_] -> G[Index[list][i], Index[list][j], Index[list][k]],
   ...}]
```

where `F, G, ...` are some other functions - for example, I would want

```
replace[f[b, c]]
```

to return

```
F[2, 3].
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. The problem seems to be with the function `Index` being evaluated before the symbol is input, and I don't know how to fix it. For example, if I consider the simpler replacement rule

```
replace1[expr] := ReplaceAll[expr, {f[i_, j_]-> Index[list][i]}]
```

then `replace1[f[a, b]]` returns `{}`. What I have found in other answers is the use of e.g. `Hold`, but the best I have been able to do in my case is something like

```
replace2[expr] := ReplaceAll[expr, {f[i_, j_]-> Hold[Index[list][i]]}]
```

and then release the hold, it evaluates as expected, i.e.

```
replace2[f[b, c]]//ReleaseHold --> 2
```

but for what I am doing, I need this to be done automatically so that `F` is given the argument in the replacement rule.

This is a slight simplification of the full problem, so please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I think the only problem is that you need to use [`RuleDelayed :>`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) instead of [`Rule ->`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html). That is: ``{f[i_, j_] :> Index[list][i]}``

Comment: Oh wow, it works! I feel a bit stupid now but thank you!

Comment: No problem, it's a common caveat for beginners :)